# Connecting and Programming LinkSprite Camera to Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, sd-card

I recently bought the LinkSprite color jpeg camera:
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12804
And the Arduino Wireless SD Shield:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWirelessShield

I was wondering how to connect the camera to the Arduino and how to have it take and save a picture to the sd card when a button is pressed.

Comment: What type of Arduino? The camera requires serial communication. HardwareSerial would be a good idea but that would require a Mega or Leonardo etc (board with extra serial ports). SoftwareSerial is possible but difficult to get to work at higher speed.

Comment: its an Arduino Uno r3

Comment: i have a mega also if i need that

Comment: What have you done so far to try this yourself?

Comment: Nothing really, i have been looking around to figure out how to connect it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the camera to a serial port (hardware or software serial depending on Arduino board). See further information on [wiki](http://linksprite.com/wiki/index.php5?title=JPEG_2M_Pixel_Color_Camera_Serial_Interface%28TTL_level%29).

Control the camera and fetch the image over the serial connections (see commands) and write to the SD disc.